# Show 2 overlapped pictures in the middle of the WebView

Tags: android, z-index, image, android-webview, alignment

I'd like my webView to show 2 overlapped pictures, placed in the middle of the page; well I tried this:

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/n8h7YJNGyAY/default.jpg" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute;" />
    <img src="file:///android_asset/yt_play.png" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute" />
</div>
```

and despite the pictures are shown overlapped they won't be placed centrally...how can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: can this help you? http://www.samisite.com/photo/id129.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://www.xul.fr/en/css/text-over-image.php) site. An example is:

```
<!-- language: java --> 
<div style="position:relative; height:430px">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1">
        <img src="http://www.xul.fr/css/images/cats.jpg">
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:150px;left:200px; width:600px; height:430px; z-index:2;font-size:200%;">
        <img src="http://www.xul.fr/en/css/images/here.gif" width="160" height="100">
    </div> 
</div>
```